# Scrape information - BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code goes to a website, extracts URLS and then goes to URLS it scraped (works fine up to here)

Now on this new page, I want to get some info (Author Name), however it is printing blanks

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
eachLink=[]
baseurl='https://meetinglibrary.asco.org'
for x in range (1,2):
  driver.get(f'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/results?meetingView=2020%20ASCO%20Virtual%20Scientific%20Program&page={x}')
  time.sleep(3)
  page_source = driver.page_source
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
  productlist=soup.find_all('a',class_='ng-star-inserted')
  for item in productlist:
     for link in item.find_all('a',href=True):
         eachLink.append(baseurl+link['href'])
print(eachLink)
infobox=[]
for b in eachLink:
    r=requests.get(b)
    time.sleep(1)
    soup1=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    auth=soup1.find('a',class_='asset-metadata-value link ng-star-inserted')
    print(auth)
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Its literally stated in the post, it is printing blanks....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps time.sleep(1) isn't long enough inside the eachLink loop and the page is still loading. Instead of using time.sleep (implicit wait) you could use an explicit wait to check for an expected condition.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

path = "//div[@id='YOURIDHERE']"   #change to something that should be present for eachLink

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, path) 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its help. No need to second for loop to extract authors.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
eachLink=[]
authors = []
baseurl='https://meetinglibrary.asco.org'
for x in range (1,2):
  driver.get(f'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/results?meetingView=2020%20ASCO%20Virtual%20Scientific%20Program&page={x}')
  time.sleep(120)
  page_source = driver.page_source

  soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
  productlist=soup.find_all('a',class_='ng-star-inserted')
  for auth in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'record__ellipsis'}):
      authors.append(auth.text)

  for item in productlist:
     for link in item.find_all('a',href=True):
         eachLink.append(baseurl+link['href'])
print(eachLink)
print('\n', authors, '\n')

driver.quit()
```

Comment: thank you, but i want to eventually pull more information. so i want to pull from the href page as opposed to the current page